# MS Access delete query in Java throws a java.sql.SQLException

Tags: java, ms-access, sql-delete

I am trying to do a simple delete query through java. the code I use is as follows. All other queries like a select and update query do work. ID is a value the user inputs and has been stored as a string.

```
int rs5 = fk.conn.createStatement().executeUpdate("DELETE * FROM tblKites WHERE tblKites.ID = " + ID + "");
```

and the error message is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason not to use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html#create_ps)'s?

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE * FROM tblKites WHERE tblKites.ID = ?");
preparedStatement.setString(1,idValue);
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

See **[here](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-delete-a-record/)** for a concrete example on how to delete a record using JDBC PreparedStatement.

### Note:

Since the JDBC PreparedStatement example in the above link uses Oracle database and you are using MSAccess, you can consider using [JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html) along with [UCanAccess API](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) to connect to your MSAccess database.

The additional jars that you would need in your project build path are:

```
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
hsqldb.jar
jackcess-2.1.0.jar
ucanaccess-2.0.9.5.jar
```

### Example:

The example below(works fine on JDK 8) *initializes a remote database connection*, *inserts a record* into an MS Access database and *closes the connection*.

```
/**
 * Connects to a remote MS-Access DB using JDBC/UCanAccess API.
 * 
 * ADDITIONAL JARS REQD:
 * 
 * commons-lang-2.6.jar
 * commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
 * hsqldb.jar
 * jackcess-2.1.0.jar
 * ucanaccess-2.0.9.5.jar
 * 
 */
package miscellaneous;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class ConnectRemoteDB {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        initializeConnection();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes remote database connection and inserts a record and closes the connection.
     */
    private static void initializeConnection() {
        System.out.println("Attempting Database Connection...");
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess:////IP ADDRESS/shared-folder-name/TestDB.mdb"); // Replace IP ADDRESS with the actual IP ADDRESS
            System.out.println("CONNECTION ESTABLISHED....");
            String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO Table1" + "(Name) VALUES"
                    + "(?)";
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, "Sandeep");
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("RECORD INSERTED...");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                connection.close();
                System.out.println("CONNECTION CLOSED...");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```